# Amazon Fargate - determine container startup order

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Is there a way in *Amazon Fargate* to determine the startup order of containers?
Let's say I have two containers and I want container B to start only when A is already up.
In [other Amazon ECS I could use *links*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) to achieve this, but links are not supported in Fargate's *awsvpc* network mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit way to control ordering in Fargate today, but it's [on the roadmap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/123).

Answer (score 9):

As of March 2019, this feature is now available! https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/amazon-ecs-introduces-enhanced-container-dependency-management/

The way you do this is with `dependsOn` in your task definition. e.g. if you want a container to start only after a container `foo` has started, you do

```
"dependsOn": [
   {
       "containerName": "foo",
       "condition": "START"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the AWS Task Definition wizard, you can configure this under the section "Container Definitions". Edit (or add) your container, then scroll down to the section "STARTUP DEPENDENCY ORDERING". You can choose from four options: start, complete, success, healthy.